# Why does the candump prevent missing heart beat fault?

Tags: raspberry-pi, can-bus, canopen

I have a simple CANopen application receiving and transmitting some PDOs and receiving heart beats from 2 nodes.
It works for an hour then it stops receiving heart beats. To see if I got any error frames when that happened I tried some logging with.
candump -e -x -ta -a -l any,0~0,#FFFFFFFF

now the problem disappeared. It has run for more than 4 hours. Surely I cannot have logging on for ever, so what should I do?

pi@cilix-19:~ $ uname -a
Linux cilix-19 5.15.32-v7l+ #1538 SMP Thu Mar 31 19:39:41 BST 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Does it concern only the heartbeat or PDOs as well ?

Do you are sending a heartbeat from master to nodes ? Some node consume it. A simple frame at ID: 0x700 + master node id, DLC:1, Data 05.

Could be also possible that at some point your master doesn't ACK node frames which force nodes to stop sending ... Doing a logging can prevent it ... Not sure but possible

CANopen is complex, some manufacturer doesn't implement the entire stack but only part of it.
Worth to try easy things